# Yii Framework Rights access menu

Tags: php, yii

I used Rights In Yii Framework For access the administrators 
access to good works.
But the problem is that all managers can see all menu options on the  site .
what can i do that managers are only able to see a menu that has access

Comment: What is the meaning of Right ? What have you tried ?? post the code wher u get the error

Comment: Im so sorry .edit (Rights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make items for each menu option. 
Make permissions for this menu items, with roles which you want to show them.
In your main layout( or where you output menu ):

```
$role = Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app() -> user -> Id);
            foreach ($role as $role)
                $role->name;
            if ($role->name == 'Manager' or Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser) {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->clientsUrl, 'label' => "Clients", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('clients')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->providersUrl, 'label' => "Data Providers", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('providers')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->ordersUrl, 'label' => "Orders", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('orders')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label' => "Tools", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('tools')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest)),));
            } elseif ($role->name == 'Client') {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/user/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => array('/user/client/lists'), 'label' => 'Lists', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Client.Lists')), array('url' => array('/user/orders/index', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Orders', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkaccess('User.Orders.Index')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label' => "Profile", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('tools')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest))));
            }
            elseif ($role->name == 'Provider') {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/user/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => array('/user/provider/data', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Data', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => array('/user/feeds/feeds', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Feeds', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => array('/user/payments', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Payments', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest))));
            }
```

Just an example, and sorry for long strings.